# jqm 1.4: LOADING a huge page and then show itself

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have 2 BIG HTML files: HTML1 and HTML2, both located in the same directory

HTML1 is a Multipage JQM Site
HTML2 is another Multipage JQM Site

On HTML1 I have a button that goes to HTML2 when clicked, but since HTLM2 is a very long file, I want to load it in the dom, before doing the transition to it.

Right now I am using 'window.location=HTML2.htm', but I get a white screen that last for abut 10 seconds, I guess JQM can do it smoothly with the spinner an all stuff.

I tried this instruction on button of HTMLl1:

```
$(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer( 'load', '#HTML2.html')
```

And this call back function:

```
$('#HTML2.html').on('pagecontainerload', function(event) {(':mobile-   
pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#HTML2.html',{transition:'slide',reverse:true});
```

But it didnt work

How can I load a page in the dom, and then show that page after is fully loaded?

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Can you split your page HTML2 into single pages to make it lighter?

Comment: No really, that HTML2 is generated automatically by a desktop APP, it varies from user to user. In some cases it can be 1KB in otther 5MB or even more,